# how to use trickle to limit upload bandwith from .sh file?

Tags: shell, upload, ubuntu-18.04, bandwidth

I want to limit the upload bandwidth limit of the linux version of 115.com webapp. This webapp actually is run by "sh /usr/local/115/115.sh". If I do
`trickle -s -u 5 sh /usr/local/115/115.sh`, then the upload limit is not in effect.

The inside of /usr/local/115/115.sh is

`#!/bin/sh`
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/115/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` `export PATH=/usr/local/115:$PATH`
`/bin/bash -c "exec -a $0 /usr/local/115/115 > /dev/null 2>&1" $0`

I feel I need to put the trickle command inside the 115.sh. How exactly should I do it? Thanks

I tried
`trickle -s -u 5 /bin/bash -c "exec -a $0 /usr/local/115/115 > /dev/null 2>&1" $0`
`/bin/bash -c "exec -a trickle -s -u 5 $0 /usr/local/115/115 > /dev/null 2>&1" $0`

and

`/bin/bash -c "exec -a $0 trickle -s -u 5 /usr/local/115/115 > /dev/null 2>&1" $0`

but still the speed limit is not effective.

Comment: just guessing here, but try `/bin/bash -c "exec -a trickle $0 -s -u 5 /usr/local/115/115 > /dev/null 2>&1" $0`. Note how `trickle` is now the first cmd that will be `exec`ed. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @shellter!  Unfortunately the app won't start in this way. I'm quite puzzled by the $0...

Comment: take out the `>/dev/null 2>&1` and see if there is anything useful in the output. And go thru the 3 variations of the invocation to see if the messages change. Again, I have no experience with trickle or 115, but general shell scripting principles. Could also try leaving out the `exec -a`. Good luck.